# python: dispatch method with string input

Tags: python

I need to write a method that takes in 3 arguments:

1. a `string` with the name of a function
2. an ordered `list` of arguments to that function.  This includes arguments with default values and `*varargs`, but does not include `**kwargs`
3. a `dict` representing any additional keyword arguments, or `None` if there are none

And I need to use this input to retrieve a function and call it.  For example:

```
def dispatch(name, args, kwargs=None):
    do_magic_here(name, args, kwargs)

def meth1():
    print "meth1"

def meth2(a, b):
    print "meth2: %s %s" % (a, b)

def meth3(a, **kwargs):
    print "meth3: " + a
    for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
        print "%s: %s" % (k,v)
```

And I need to be able to call things like this:

```
>>> dispatch("meth1", [])
meth1
>>> dispatch("meth2", [1, 3])
meth2: 1 3
>>> dispatch("meth3", [1], {"hello":2, "there":3})
meth3: 1
hello: 2
there: 3
```

I could do this:

```
def do_magic_here(name, args, kwargs=None):
    if name=="meth1":
        meth1()
    if name=="meth2":
        meth2(args[0], args[1])
    if name=="meth3":
        meth3(args[0], **kwargs)
```

But I'm trying to dispatch like 40 methods, and that number may expand, so I'm hoping there's a more programmatic way to do it.   I'm looking at something with `getattr`, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just use

```
def dispatch(name, *args, **kwargs):
    func_name_dict[name](*args, **kwargs)
```

with

```
func_name_dict = {'meth1':meth1,
                  'meth2':meth2,
                  ...}
```

Allowing you to pass `args` and `kwargs` through more naturally and transparently:

```
>>> dispatch("meth2", 1, 3)
meth2: 1 3
```

You can of course use `globals()` or `locals()` in place of the dict, but you might need to be careful about which functions in each namespace you do or don't want to expose to the caller

Comment: It's notable that `dispatch` does not take `*args` or `**kwargs`, but rather an actual list and dictionary.  does that make a difference?  It must be defined this way, because of the framework in which I'm working

Comment: Unless you really have to pass lists and dicts through, I would do it this way; it's the more natural way to pass unknown args around in Python (e.g. decorators, method overrides)

Comment: @ewok You can still unpack lists via `*` and dicts via `**`. Maybe you should change the default value for  `kwargs` to `{}`

Comment: @ewok just to elaborate on schwobaseggl's point, you can now use `dispatch(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit i think he means that if he passed in say `[1], {'a':2}` these would get interpreted as args where the first arg is a `list` and second is a `dict`. To get around that you could do something like `dispatch = lambda name, args, kwargs: func_name_dict[name](*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @BAH Yeah you could of course define it as `dispact(name, args, kwargs)`, but my point was that if `args` and `kwargs` are a list and a dict you can *call* the function with the unpacking `*`s

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, `getattr` will get you there.

```
class X:
    def a(self):
        print('a called')
    def b(self, arg):
        print('b called with ' + arg)

x = X()
getattr(x, 'a')()
# a called
getattr(x, 'b')('foo')
# b called with foo
```

Just like `getattr` handles methods and fields the same way, you can handle 
functions and variables not associated with a class by referencing `locals()` or `globals()`.

If you want to refer to a function in the global scope:

```
globals()['meth'](args)
```

For example:

```
def dispatch(name, *args, **kwargs):
  globals()[name](*args, **kwargs)

dispatch('meth3', 'hello', foo='bar')
# meth3: hello
# foo: bar
```

Remember in Python you can always pass a list of arguments or dict of keyword arguments using the `**`:

```
dispatch('meth3', *['hello'], **{'foo':'bar'})
```

If you truly prefer to pass arguments as list/dict to `dispatch`:

```
def dispatch(name, args, kwargs):
  globals()[name](*args, **kwargs)

dispatch('meth3', ['hello'], {'foo': 'bar'})
```

Comment: What if the methods are not in a class?

Comment: Then they are not *methods* but *functions*. I'll update the answer.