# Passing arguments to dispatch methods

Tags: python, django, dispatch

1. I am relatively new to Python and Django.

I am parsing Excel sheets and want to store the data in a DB (MySQL). The information in which table the data is stored is available through the Excel sheet. I'd like to use a dispatch table to decide which Object is stored. The fields needed can vary.

I found something that I hoped would work, but unfortunately does not:

[python: dispatch method with string input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270322/python-dispatch-method-with-string-input)

```
func_name_dict = {
    'Assay': Assay.objects.get_or_create()
}

def dispatch(name, *args, **kwargs):
    return func_name_dict[name](**kwargs)

dispatch('Assay', name='ChIP-Seq')
```

I would hope that the new object would get stored or fetched and returned to the caller.

What seems to happen is that the 3 existing DB records (which all have a different name) are fetched:

```
website.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Assay -- 
it returned 3!
```

Comment: I believe your dict shouldn't call the function but rather just reference it e.g. 
   `{ 'Assay': Assay.objects.get_or_create}`

Comment: New Error
```TypeError: dispatch() got multiple values for argument 'name'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the method which hi parameters and storing the result in the dict, rather than string the callable method itself. You should do:

```
func_name_dict = {
    'Assay': Assay.objects.get_or_create
}
```

ie without the parentheses.

(Although I'm not sure of the point of a dispatch dict like this if you only have one entry.)

**Edit after comment**

Well indeed you have two arguments called `name`, one as the positional parameter and one in the kwargs. You will need to call the first param something that will never be in the kwargs - for example, `dispatch_func_name`, or whatever.

Comment: There will be of course several methods once I get the one working. Removing the brackets give me a new error:
```TypeError: dispatch() got multiple values for argument 'name'```

Comment: Excellent, that was the culprit. Thank you Daniel!